# Sending user to view from search results

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'd like to implement a search into my app.  I'm planning to use a left swipe, like the Spotlight search.  Would that violate anything with Apple?

My app is tableview based.  The user can drill down a few levels before reaching a detail view. I'm considering two options for implementing the search:

1.) From the search results, I display lower level topics.  Meaning, once a user clicks a search result, they will open a detail view.  Should I back the user out of the search, navigate the UI down to the detail view...or just show the detail view (option #2)?

2.) If I just popup the detail view, it will be out of context.  Once finished with the detail view, the user will not be able to navigate backwards to the top level. They will basically already be there (search results).  Or is that how it should be - just put the user back on the search results view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it'd get rejected, but it sounds weird as I've never seen it in an app before. Why not just put the search bar in the first row of the table as in the iPod app?

You probably could also mimic the iPod behavior when "backing out" of Search results.

But yeah, this isn't really programming related.

Comment: Yep - that's exactly what I need. I haven't used the iPod enough to even notice this feature.

Comment: I've checked out the UISearchBar and the search display controller but can't get any of them to operate like the iPod search.  Do you know how that is done? The tableview must be pulled down to reveal the search.  The cancel button only appears when you type into the search field.  The original tableview will also dim.

Comment: I haven't tried this myself, but my guess is to put the Search in the first row but then scroll the table view down to the 2nd in the viewWillAppear method.